# Swagger Request URL issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger

Running into an issue where my `Request URL` where it appears to be two conjoined urls.

It appears to be: `http://https://chartpay.dev.infolock.com//api/invoices`

I'm not sure 1. what happened to create this, and 2. how to remedy it.

My swagger code in the controller is...

```
  swagger_path '/invoices' do
    operation :get do
      key :description, 'Returns all invoices'
      key :operationId, 'index'
      key :tags, [
          'Invoice'
      ]
      response 200 do
        key :description, 'Invoice'
        schema do
          key :type, :array
          items do
            key :'$ref', :invoice
          end
        end
      end
      response :default do
        key :description, 'unexpected error'
        schema do
          key :'$ref', :ErrorModel
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Just a wild guess. The double"/" may be due to version definition. e.g. https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json has version set to v2. For your case, not sure if you can set it to nil to replace "//" with "/". Hope this helps.

Comment: @wing328 You were right it was an issue with the `:basePath` AND providing `key :host, Rails.application.config.host` which wasn't needed. Thanks for your wild guess. If you want to post an answer I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double"/" may be due to version definition. e.g. petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json has version set to v2. For your case, not sure if you can set it to nil to replace "//" with "/".

Update from @cheeseFry: 
It's an issue with the :basePath AND providing key :host, Rails.application.config.host which wasn't needed